# comparing two strings with comma separated values

Tags: c++

Is there any way by which we can compare two strings having comma separates values?

To make it clear:

```
string S1 = "a,b,c,d,e"
string S2 = "c,d"
string S3 = "a,b,e"          //where string S3 is got by subtracting S2 from S1 (S1 - S2)
```

Is it possible to do this with some function?

Comment: Please tag homework with a homework tag, I also cannot tell what you're trying to ask here.

Comment: Homework tag appears to be discouraged. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812

Comment: @Matt: not really, arbitrary retagging based on a feeling is discouraged. Instead it's better to ask the OP whether or not it is, so that answers may be adapted.

Comment: when asking such a question, you should tell us what you have attempted, so that we can point the flaws in your reasoning or algorithm. You don't learn if you don't try.

Comment: @Matthieu Looking further I found a comment by Jeff Atwood not saying but implying it could/should be used.  My main issue is the confusion in the community can be off-putting for a new member trying to get their bearings.  My very first question was edited to take off the tag and I was told not to use it.   @vidhya sorry to hijack your post off on a tangent.  I'll stop beating this horse.

Answer (score 9):

If I got what you want right, you want to get the elements that are not in both strings.

Here's how I would do it:

1. Split both a and b using `,` as a separator.
2. Store the result in two sets (`std::set` for instance)
3. Compute the difference of these two sets (for example, using `std::set_difference`)
4. Convert the resulting set to a string by gluing each element together using `,`

Comment: @vidhya Sorry, but I won't do your homework for you. Get your Google-Fu on, like every programmer does.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing this is a homework assignment, so you won't get any code from me.

If I understand the question, you're talking about the "set difference", not a comparision; that is, finding the elements of one set that are not in another. To do this, you'd need

1. A data structure to represent a set. You may be allowed to use `std::set` (or `multiset`), or you may need to design your own.
2. A function, or constructor, to read the values from a string, looking for commas that separate them. If you're allowed to use libraries, then `std::stringstream` might be useful.
3. A function to calculate the difference between two sets (either by removing one set from the other, or creating a new set with the correct members). Again, if you can use the library, have a look at `std::set_difference`.
4. A function to convert the set into a string (the inverse of the function in 2) to give the final result. As in 2, `std::stringstream` would be useful.