# C++: Comparing two strings

Tags: c++, stdstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [comparing two strings with comma seperated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884283/comparing-two-strings-with-comma-seperated-values)

I am working in C++, where I have two strings:

```
string str1 = "1,4,8,",
       str2 = "4,1,8,";
```

Both strings contains comma separated values. Now I just want to check whether all the elements in `str1` also exist in `str2`, regardless of their position. Is there any direct way to check this? Do I need to write custom code for this?

Comment: Why use a string to represent this data? Why not a `std::set<int>`?

Comment: I would split those into tokens, sort them, then check if all the elements are the same.

Comment: Those are comma-terminated strings; CSV would not have the trailing comma after the 8.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as C++ is concerned, those strings are just sequences of characters. If you apply meaning to those characters (such as "comma separated values"), then you'll have to write some code to extract the data and deal with it.

I would do something like:

- split the string on ','
- convert each sequence of digits into an integer (skipping over empty elements)
- insert those integers into a set (one for each input string)
- compare the sets

It's up to you to determine what kind of integer to use.

Comment: The problem with a set is that they have to be unique (or, at least, each set will contain only unique values).  He might want to also ensure that both lists have the same number of duplicates, in which case a plain `std::set<int>` won't work, since it won't keep track of a count.

Comment: @Merlyn: fair call, so @Jame: if that applies to you try `std::map<int, int>`, i.e. from key to count.

Comment: @Tony: what's wrong with `std::multiset`?

Comment: @Mike: nothing - either way - though if you know most elements repeat many times then `map` may use less memory, whereas if repeats are rare a `multiset` may use less....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to write custom code, although not a lot of it. Once you figure out the algorithm you can post here if you have further questions on how to implement each part.